# Given a Magnetic Field vector, what is the Electric Field, charge density, & current density?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I tried searching for this before having to ask, so please forgive me if I missed a previous question similar to mine. This is a Grad class, so I may be unnecessarily too careful in not assuming things to make things simple. So please let me know of that as well.

So the true question is framed as such:

> 3 fields are given. (1 Electric field & 2 Magnetic field.)
>
> For each field, does it satisfy Maxwell's Equations? Then find charge and current densities.

My problem with this is that I think there needs to be at least one more piece of information to get the two left. Am I wrong in thinking that?

I don't want someone to do the homework for me, so I'll keep it general as possible and concentrate on one of the B-fields.

> B($\vec{x}$,t) = $\alpha$$f(t) \hat{r}$ , Where $\alpha$ is a constant and we are in spherical coordinates.

If someone can help me with the logic of getting the E-field and the charge/current densities, I would really appreciate it. (Or even proving if one or all of those are zero.)

The above one is the simplest as the divergence and curl of B is zero. So time derivative of E and current density can be related easily, but in a general way: $\dot{E} = -1/\epsilon_{0} \vec{j}$ I can integrate to get $\vec{E}$ but the current density is unknown, so I left it in the integral as I have to assume a general geometry and not one which has symmetry.

If $\rho$ & $\vec{j}$ were zero as in vacuum, then I can get E field easily.

I'm just really stuck here.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does the field ${\bf B} = \alpha f(t) {\bf \hat r}$ satisfy the no magnetic monopoles Maxwell equation?

$$
\nabla \cdot {\bf B} = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \ \alpha f(t) \right) = \frac{2 \alpha}{r} f(t) \neq 0 
$$
unless $\alpha = 0$, or $f(t) = 0$, then no, this is not divergence-less. Try and picture what this magnetic field would look like, all radial, it never loops back...hence it is not divergence-less.

I can help more if you provide more info, if the above is not clear, please let me know, but in general you are on the correct path use the Maxwell relations to derive functions that relate to the E and B field, you might even use the potential formulation $(\phi, {\bf A})$ of the maxwell equations for more help as one is a scalar.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I stated the correct thing while looking at the wrong part of the problem.

But more importantly, I asked my professor about it and he said that I made it more complicated than he intended. Apparently we are allowed to make assumptions like $\vec{j}$ is zero and such as long I can run through all of Maxwell's equations and come back to my starting part.

So that made my life a lot easier.

Thanks for your help!